# Number of tabs in ActionBar

Tags: java, android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar

Android's `ActionBar` has a mode `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. Using ActionBarSherlock 3.5.1 I have set this `ActionBar` and addded 5 tabs. On 2.x devices I see all tabs without horizontal scrolling. On 4.0.x I see only 3 tabs with scrollable layout. `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` of ActionBar can contain max 3 tabs in ICS? If yes, could I hack this somehow? I know, i could create custom `TabHost`, but it would be quite time consuming to implement it with ViewPager between tab views.

[image: 2.x devices]

[image: 4.0.X devices]

Comment: Same problem here. Have you find a solution?

Comment: We have created custom TabBar. Check it here: https://gist.github.com/3273440

Comment: I strongly recommend that you update to ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0. I use that version of the library for all sorts of things without issue in these API levels.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to hack anything. The ActionBar tabs have specific layout parameters that you can change pretty easily through a custom style. Google uses their own style to set them in the first place. You should take a look at this on creating custom styles. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html Since you want them to look like they way Jake Wharton has them set in ActionBarSherlock, then you could make things even easier for yourself and just rip his styles out.

Comment: Sure I use styles. The problem is the screen looks different on different Android versions. I am looking for reason, why this happens.

Comment: I don't see any option in the style regarding controlling the scrollable state of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with action bar sherlock, and this post helped me.
[How to manage the width of ActionBar navigation tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740199/how-to-manage-the-width-of-actionbar-navigation-tabs)

Important part is

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```