# How to manage the width of ActionBar navigation tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and have an ActionBar with navigation tabs in it. I want the tabs to auto-size based on the size of the text in them, but there seems to be a style or a setting somewhere that is forcing them to use a minimum size. So for example in the screenshot the tab "Very Long Tab" has no padding (in accordance with the styling I applied) but the tabs marked "T" have a great deal of padding, despite me setting padding to 0dp.

[image]

As you can see below I've tried a brute-force approach by setting various attributes on several styles, but I've not succeeded yet.

How do I control the padding/width in the action bar tabs?

```
<style
    name="CustomActivity"
    parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
    >
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/customActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/customActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="customActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="customActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: checkout: [How to make Andorid's ActionBar/TabWidget LinearLayout to wrap it's children][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024127/how-to-make-andorids-actionbar-tabwidget-linearlayout-to-wrap-its-children/28223519#28223519

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From that screen shot it looks like you are testing on ICS which is good since you will be observing the behavior of the native action bar rather than think it is a bug with ActionBarSherlock.

Basically the action bar will attempt to expand tabs to take up an equal amount of space if there is enough room to do so in order to provide a cleaner look when there are only a few tabs.

By setting the `actionBarTabTextStyle` padding to zero you are actually making the problem worse since now the text in the first tab has nothing around it to prevent it from touching the dividers and edge of screen. If you increase the padding (or return it to default) you should see one of two things:

1. The text will wrap to two lines.
2. The tab bar will convert tabs to simply be as wide as their content and allow for horizontal scrolling.

I'm inclined to think that the former will happen due to the very thin widths of your second through fourth tab. Unfortunately this is just how the tab bar behaves and we need to just try an accomodate its behavior accordingly.

If possible, try to create tab labels that have a more unified width which will likely trigger the second state mentioned above. Keep testing with ICS so that you can ensure the behavior you're seeing is from the platform and then when running on pre-ICS you should get the same behavior from the library.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Unfortunately even I rip out all my styles, the tabs with short text still have a great deal of padding, and in my scenario that padding is causing the tabs to scroll horizontally. In the screenshot there is actually another tab off to the right, not visible. That's actually the issue, to stop the tabs scrolling by reducing the padding on tabs with short text titles. I've not seen any text wrap, though I want to reduce the padding not let it wrap. you're right that this is ICS, on a Galaxy Nexus so I figure this is a native issue rather than an ABS issue.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you unfortunately. I don't remember much of the tab code nor its styles. I just know that it modifies the children based on a few conditions in order to lay them out in a special way. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're just using the theme for the pre 4.0 android mode of ActionBarSherlock?

From http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html:

> Mirrored Attributes
>
> Due to limitations in Android's theming system any theme
>   customizations must be declared in two attributes. The normal
>   android-prefixed attributes apply the theme to the native action bar
>   and the unprefixed attributes are for the custom implementation. Since
>   both theming APIs are exactly the same you need only reference your
>   customizations twice rather than having to implement them twice.
>
> The easiest way to convey exactly what this entails is with an
>   example. The following is the full theme from the “Styled” example
>   mentioned above:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Override this class in project ActionBarSherlock ./ActionbarSherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java

```
 @Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     Re-measure if we went beyond our maximum size.
    if (mParent.mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mParent.mMaxTabWidth) {

      //do nothing , override by me for ActionBarTabs not rezize never

    }
}
```

Original code from

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // Re-measure if we went beyond our maximum size.
    if (mParent.mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mParent.mMaxTabWidth) {
        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mParent.mMaxTabWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

When run , that code in android 2.3.3 works fine when my Tabs not broken line, but in android 4.4 not works.